# WordPress cron running twice

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron, cron

I have the following code that creates a CSV and then sends an email:

```
function generate_and_send_csv()
  {

    // Removed CSV code for ease of reading
    wp_mail('email@address.com', 'New Data Files', 'You have received new data files.', $headers, $filepath);

  }
//Create the cron event
if (!wp_next_scheduled('generate_send_csv')) {
    wp_schedule_event('1488934800', 'daily', 'generate_send_csv');
}
// Run it
add_action('generate_send_csv', 'generate_and_send_csv');
```

I then have the following cron set up in cPanel:

```
php /home/user/public_html/wp-cron.php
```

After installing the Cronjob Scheduler by chrispage1 plugin, I can see the plugin is correctly scheduling the cron job for 1AM every day. This runs fine, but for some reason I get the email twice.

I know it can't be anything in my code because when I click the "run" option in the Cron Scheduler plugin, I get the email once. Are there any known issues with WordPress running duplicate cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

I tried WP Crontrol instead and it turned out that two cron jobs were being created for `generate_send_csv`. To fix this, I created the crons within activation hooks and deactivation hooks as follows:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation' );
add_action( 'generate_send_csv', 'generate_and_send_csv' );

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event('1488979800', 'daily', 'generate_send_csv');
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_deactivation' );

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'generate_send_csv' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, but I can't rely on activation hooks because I schedule events dynamically, I can't go by deactivating activating the plugin every time an user creates a new scheduled processing event. This seems to be a fairly common problem with WP but there seems be no proper way to solve this problem. Do you have any other ideias?

Comment: I ended up using the Transients API, as suggest in [106028](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308787/106028)