# How to make sure that only one wp_cron() runs at a time?

Tags: php, wp-cron, transient

I have around 20 `wp_cron()` functions like the following code. Almost all crons run hourly; a few are daily.

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
  //Complex Code
}
```

To increase server performance, and so as not to keep getting server limit messages from hosting companies, I want to make sure that only one cron runs at a given time... Is it possible?

---

**The current accepted  answer is great, but I have following question, that's why I start a bounty for this question.**

Please read the accepted answer at first.

Let assume  Cron 1 runs, My code of cron2 won't running because still we are inside the 5 minute or first cron is running still, but because of `wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );` running for cron2 I think WordPress consider as cron2 runs..... So basically code of cron2 code never run..... Or I have misunderstand something?

Comment: No, you understand it correctly. I'll update my answer with some solutions for your problem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible...

And to be honest, it's often very important to do this... WP Scheduler sometimes tends to cause problems, when cron tasks are long...

### So how I solve this problem?

I use [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to implement semaphores...

Here's the code:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
  // if some other my_task is already running, stop
  if ( get_transient( 'my_task_function_semaphore' ) ) return;

  // set semaphore for 5 minutes
  set_transient( 'my_task_function_semaphore', true, 5*60 );

  // DO YOUR STUFF

  delete_transient( 'my_task_function_semaphore' );
}
```

Why do I use transients in this case? Because:

- They're part of WP.
- They're easy to use and efficient.
- They won't cause deadlocks. Let's say my cron task can get killed (some error may occur, or it runs too long and gets killed, and so on). In such case it won't delete semaphore, so all future tasks won't work. Using transients solves this problem, because after some time transient will be deleted.

### And what if there are many different actions to do?

So let's say there are many different cron tasks, that should never run in same time, but we still want them all to run...

If we use the solution with semaphore and use only one semaphore for all of these tasks, then some of them may never run. So what to do then?

In such case you should change your thinking. You don't have some independent tasks, but a queue of tasks to do. So you should implement it in this way.

So:

1. You add some kind of queue (you can use an array and store it as option, or add a custom DB table).
2. You use your currently WP cron hourly event to add tasks to queue.
3. You add second WP cron tasks which runs much more often and it "eats" tasks from queue one by one. This "eater" task should use semaphore to ensure that only one task runs at a moment.

Comment: Thanks, but I am sorry, I never used transient before... But I am tring to understand the code. Why did you set 5 minutes for transient because you delete the transient using `delete_transient()`. So that time matters? I mean which ever time you put to `set_transient`, it is deleted just after the my work is done... So why there is a time?

Comment: Because some errors may occur. Take a look at the last bullet point.

Comment: Thanks, great... Just one question. As I understand,  If I use `my_task_function_semaphore` as the name for transient, I must use all other crons to the same name?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson it depends on what you want to achieve... If only one task should work in given moment, then yes - all tasks should use the same transient name as semaphore

Comment: Another question I have in mind. What happen if we remove `delete_transient( 'my_task_function_semaphore' );`? Can it be a problem?

Comment: Then cron tasks using that semaphore will have to wait until the transient is removed automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Let assume I remove `delete_transient( 'my_task_function_semaphore' );`..... Cron 1 runs, My code of cron2 not running because still we are inside the 5 minute, but because of `wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );` running for cron2 I think WordPress consider as cron2 runs..... So basically code if cron2 code never run..... Or I have misunderstand something?

Comment: It is really appreciate if you can give me a answer for last comment of me.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson It’s hard to answer that question, because it depends on many details. But in general it is possible that something like this happens. If you perform multiple operations on hourly basis and they’re not independent, then it is better to implement them as one action. But again - it’s hard to guess what your actions do exactly and it is another question, and a very broad one, I guess...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I will more study about theme because my next project totally depends on cron. Thanks again

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż +1. Also, I'm not sure, but I think you'll not get the bounty if the answer was posted before the bounty was initiated. Not sure about edits though.

Comment: @Fayaz I’m not sure too, but forget the bounty - I hope this will answer the question completely now :)

Comment: I've done similar things with Job Queue tools like Gearman. This implementation may help: https://github.com/10up/WP-Minions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is perfect, but sorry I could not give 50 rep. I ask a question on meta https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/how-to-give-old-bounty-without-starting-new-one

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson No problem. I’m glad it helped you :)

Comment: The use of transients is a lovely simple solution, but it's not entirely robust.  Once we pass the transient expiry, the transient will remove itself and another job is always free to start, even if one is already running.  Similarly, if the job doesn't delete the transient, but finishes early, the next job will always have to wait until expiry.  I'm sure this is 'robust enough' for most uses.  You'd need something like [PHP's flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) that auto-releases the lock on process termination, not entirely trivial to get right.

Comment: @BrianC the cron job should not take a long time. So yes - the transient expiration time should be set to a longer time that is needed. And the expiration is a good thing - it prevents deadlocks to occur.